# Pyramid authorization: permission is ignored

Tags: python, authorization, pyramid

I'm trying to add authorization to my Pyramid app but it looks like it's getting completely ignored.  Since everyone is denied the 'view' permission, why am I still able to view the 'home' route?

security.py:

```
from pyramid.security import Allow, Everyone, Deny, Authenticated
from .models import Roles

def groupfinder(userid, request):
    print('userid: %s' % userid)
    return None


class RootFactory(object):
    __acl__ = [(Deny, Everyone, 'view')]

    def __init__(self, request):
        pass
```

__init__.py:

```
from .security import groupfinder
from pyramid.authentication import AuthTktAuthenticationPolicy
from pyramid.authorization import ACLAuthorizationPolicy
from pyramid.config import Configurator
from sqlalchemy import engine_from_config

from .models import (
    DBSession,
    Base,
    )


def main(global_config, **settings):
    """ This function returns a Pyramid WSGI application.
    """
    engine = engine_from_config(settings, 'sqlalchemy.')
    DBSession.configure(bind=engine)
    Base.metadata.bind = engine

    authn_policy = AuthTktAuthenticationPolicy(secret='secret', callback=groupfinder, hashalg='sha512')
    authz_policy = ACLAuthorizationPolicy()
    config = Configurator(settings=settings, root_factory='vip_backend.security.RootFactory')
    config.set_authentication_policy(authn_policy)
    config.set_authorization_policy(authz_policy)

    config = Configurator(settings=settings)
    config.include('pyramid_mako')
    config.add_static_view('static', 'static', cache_max_age=3600)
    config.add_route('home', '/')
    config.scan()
    return config.make_wsgi_app()
```

views.py:

```
from pyramid.response import Response
from pyramid.view import view_config


@view_config(route_name='home', permission='view')
def home(request):
    return Response(body='You are here.')
```

Comment: Ugh, nevermind...I just realized I initialize the config twice.  The dangers of copy/paste!